# list of customized integers

Tags: c#, struct, bit

I need some help in C#..
I need to develop a module in C# which will consume a lot of CPU&RAM, every bit counts!!
I'm suppose to create a list that will hold structs, one of the fields will be a customized integer.
Integer can be only 0,1,2 (binary: 00,01,10)- so I don't need an integer bigger than 2 bits.
That's preferable to the smallest built-in integer - byte, that has 8 bits.
I need the new integer to function as a regular integer, so I won't need to use casting(very expensive) or any other special operations when I try to do a simple value assigning or any simple arithmetic calculation..
Is there a way for me to define the custom integer inside the struct, without changing the rest of my code in the main program?
If you could please write me a short struct or refer me to a similar implementation I would most appreciate
Many Thanks

Comment: `ushort` takes 16 bits. `byte` is the smallest with 8 bits.

Comment: But are you sure you need this? How many of these integers do you need to store? It will take more CPU to work with these, because modern CPUs are optimized for 32 or 64 bit values.

Comment: Having said all that, I guess you could implement something that used a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) underneath for compact storage.

Comment: There can also be a problem of alignment when something of that size is used inside a structure -- the actual structure may be larger then you expect (unless you use `[StructLayout]`).

Comment: That not very elegant and seems very "expensive" in run-time terms.. Isn't there something simple that won't mess up the rest of the code?

Comment: What I would do is merge the customized integer with a completely different field, and have an indexer to that. For example, if you have a string in the struct, you could simply allocate 2 extra bits after the `\0` to be used as storage for your customized int. But if you could merge the customized integers themselves, separately from the other fields, as Guffa suggested, it would be better.

Answer (score 5):

> "ushort, that has 4 bits"

Nope, an ushort is 16 bits. A byte is the smallest, with 8 bits.

> "Is there a way for me to define the custom integer inside the struct,
>   without changing the rest of my code in the main program?"

No, you can't make a struct that is smaller than a byte, so to make an integer that uses only two bits you have to change the collection that holds them so that it can store multiple values in a single byte.

Something like:

```
public class TwoBitArray {

  private int _len;
  private byte[] _data;

  public TwoBitArray(int size) {
    _len = size;
    _data = new byte[(size + 3) / 4];
  }

  public int this[int index] {
    get {
      if (index < 0 || index >= _len) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
      int ofs = index / 4;
      int shift = (index & 3) * 2;
      return (_data[ofs] >> shift) & 3;
    }
    set {
      if (index < 0 || index >= _len) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
      if (value < 0 || value > 3) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
      int ofs = index / 4;
      int shift = (index & 3) * 2;
      int mask = 3 << shift;
      _data[ofs] = (byte)((_data[ofs] & (255 - mask)) | (value << shift));
    }
  }

}
```